# Populate a drop down list and disable options based on a property

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, properties, populate

I'm trying to populate a `select` list in ajax with jQuery. In AJAX I retrieve the results like it:

```
var select = $("#my_select");
select.empty();
$.each(data,function(k,v){
    select.append(new Option(v.VALUE, v.ID));
});
```

It's working. But thanks to my ajax script I retrieve another property: `DEFINED`. I would like to disable the line (the user cannot select the value) in the drop down list when `v.DEFINED = "no"`

I do not know how to do that, I have tried to do that, but it's not working:

```
if (v.DEFINED == "yes") {
    select.append('<option value="' + v.VALUE + '">' + v.VALUE + '</option>');
} else {
    select.append('<option value="' + v.VALUE + '" disabled="disabled">' + v.VALUE + '</option>');
}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: What value does the `DEFINED` property have?

Comment: DEFINED can have the value "yes" or "no"

Comment: In that case your code should be working fine; http://jsfiddle.net/0tm02h61/. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan says your code is fine, are you able to show the object returned by your ajax?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree with you. I have removed my answer.

Comment: It's ok in fact the ajax returns true and false and not yes and no. I done the update and it's working